# How to group array entries by key and by key value in jq?

Tags: json, group-by, jq

Given this json:

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "level": "H2",
      "id": "id1"
    },
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "level": "H1",
      "id": "id2"
    },
    {
      "country": "CZ",
      "level": "H2",
      "id": "id3"
    },
    {
      "country": "IT",
      "level": "H2",
      "id": "id4"
    },
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "level": "H3",
      "id": "id5"
    },
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "level": "H3",
      "id": "id6"
    },
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "level": "H4”,
      "id": "id7"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to group this by country and in two levels, one having the H1 and H2 entries, and the other having the H3 and H4 entries. Furthermore, I would like that ids and levels to be encapsulated in an object called "entities" like follows:

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id2",
          "level": "H1"
        },
        {
          "id": "id1",
          "level": "H2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "CZ",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id3",
          "level": "H2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "IT",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id4",
          "level": "H2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id5",
          "level": "H3"
        },
        {
          "id": "id6",
          "level": "H3"
        },
        {
          "id": "id7",
          "level": "H4"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am quite new to jq. Could anyone help me doing this in jq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide `group_by` with two criteria: one is simply the value of `.country`, the other is the containedness of `.level` in a given set of values (here, using `IN` with `H1` and `H2`, which evaluates to a boolean). After the grouping, use a `map` to rectify the shapes of the individual groups as desired.

```bash
.hits |= (
  group_by(.country, IN(.level; "H1", "H2")) 
  | map((first | {country}) + {entities: map({id, level})})
)
```

```json
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "country": "CZ",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id3",
          "level": "H2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "IT",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id4",
          "level": "H2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id5",
          "level": "H3"
        },
        {
          "id": "id6",
          "level": "H3"
        },
        {
          "id": "id7",
          "level": "H4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "PT",
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "id1",
          "level": "H2"
        },
        {
          "id": "id2",
          "level": "H1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A1tvPLh3wNa)

Answer (score 2):

In case it is helpful to someone: if we start with something very similar to the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77108216/84940), but with minor changes for readability ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Uxa_YJC8yl6)):

```
.hits |= [

  group_by(.country, (.level == "H1" or .level == "H2")) []
  | { country : first.country, entities: [.[] | { level, id }] }

]
```

we can accommodate an arbitrary complex grouping criteria as follows ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/e3jDkn5yM6G)):

```
def transform:
  if    . == "H1" then 1
  elif  . == "H2" then 1
  elif  . == "H3" then 2
  elif  . == "H4" then 2
  else  3
  end;

.hits |= [
 group_by(.country, (.level | transform)) []
 | { country : first.country, entities: [.[] | del(.country) ] }
]
```

It also keeps all properties except `.country` instead of having to provide a whitelist of values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution which uses of the `,` filter which generates multiple outputs for a single input. It also uses the fact that iterating inside an object "multiplies" this object (generating multiple objects, one for each iterated value)

```
.hits
| group_by(.country)
| map({
    country: first.country,
    entities: map({id,level})
    | (map(select(IN("H1","H2";.level))), map(select(IN("H3","H4";.level))))
    | select(length>0)
})
| { hits: . }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward solution using the generic stream-oriented function `aggregate_by/2`:

```
def aggregate_by(s; f):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += [$x]);

aggregate_by(.hits[]; .level)
| [aggregate_by( (.H1 + .H2)[]; .country)] +
  [aggregate_by( (.H3 + .H4)[]; .country)]
| map( to_entries[]
       | {country: .key, entities: (.value | map(del(.country))) } )
| {hits: [ . ]}
```

Using `aggregate_by` here not only makes the solution quite straightforward
once one understands what it does, but also makes the program relatively efficient in comparison to `group_by/1` in that the latter relies on sorting.